# Storing events to a database while app is running in background

Tags: android, realm, android-service, foreground-service, android-application-class

I want my app to store events(fired by an SDK) to a database (using realm) even if the app is in background. My concept was to use a Service that makes some SDK initialization and listening on the events. By starting this Service within the `onCreate()` method of my custom Application class I wanted to assure that the Service is kept alive while the app is in background so that I don't miss any event to be stored into the database.

But now since Android 8 background services are no more allowed. But I don't want to use a Foreground Service because I would need to display a notification. And I don't want the user to know that events are stored in a database in background. I think that information is to technical for normal users.

I realized the problem when `Application.onCreate()` wanted to start the service but an exception was thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start
>   service Intent {
>   cmp=my.package.name.debug/my.package.name.service.MyService }: app is
>   in background uid UidRecord{94b2e4a u0a204 SVC  idle
>   change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

Remarkably the exception is thrown if I kill the task of my app. So  `Application.onCreate()` is called if I kill the app.

Finally I am not sure if a Service is the right thing to use for my use case.

I have two questions:

1. What kind of component to use if I want to store events in a database also if my app is in background?
2. Why does killing the app trigger Application's `onCreate()`?

Comment: u can still do background services in oreo. use a job scheduler

Comment: this might be useful for you. https://medium.com/@nivedithagemini/handling-background-execution-limits-android-oreo-cdb7c071e6a2

Comment: @DroiDev Yes but wouldn't a job scheduler be useful if I trigger something actively? In my case I listen to events and store passively i.e. when the event is fired. Wouldn't a JobScheduler just run a job and terminate if it comes to an end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `workmanager` for your particular case.

It can fulfill all your requirements and it has guaranteed execution even if **app is in background** or **device gets rebooted.**

Check [this (link to example code for WorkManager)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/) out for more info on WorkManager Api.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer related to my 2nd question:

I start my Service using `Service.START_STICKY`. If the app is killed, the service is killed too. A sticky Service recreates itself if it is killed. And because the Application class starts the Service in my case, the Application is recreated, too. But still the app is in background and then I run into Application's `onCreate()` and the App crashes because Oreo doesn't allow any Service to be started while the app is in background.

Edit:

Answer to my first question: After reading more in Android's official documentation I come to the following conclusion: It really seems that a foreground service is the wrong choice here because the user does not need to know about events stored to the DB. A JobScheduler (or the newer Workmanager) is more for one-time or periodic jobs. So a mixed started/bound service seems to be the right choice here.